# Angular 16 trying to dynamically load a component inside a modal component using ViewContainerRef and createComponent. No error but nothing loads

Tags: angular

The meat of the code is in the loadComponent, I'm currently hardcoding a component ListComponent for testing purposes, and again, the modal opens but no listcomponent in it:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { NavigationService } from 'src/app/services/navigation/navigation.service';
import { ListComponent } from 'src/app/views/list/list.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'ct-modal',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule, ListComponent],
    templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() show = false;
    @ViewChild('modalContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container!: ViewContainerRef;

    private modalSubscription!: Subscription;

    constructor(
        private navigationService: NavigationService,
        private injector: Injector
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.modalSubscription = this.navigationService
            .getModalObservable()
            .subscribe((component) => this.loadComponent(component));
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.modalSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    loadComponent(component: any) {
        this.show = true;
        if (this.container && component) {
            this.container.clear();
            this.container.createComponent(ListComponent, {
                injector: this.injector
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and the template:

```
<div *ngIf="show" class="modal-overlay">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <p>modal works!</p>
        <ng-template #modalContainer></ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

Most of the info I see online mentions the deprecated ComponentFactoryResolver

and I'm somehow not getting this doc into my brain which seems to be exactly what i need
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: try `cdRef.detectChanges()`